# Get Add Connection event of Server Explorer window inside VS package

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'm trying to fire some changes on a Menu after a new connection is added or removed from the Server Explorer window on my Visual Studio package. So I'm looking for an event that I can subscribe or any other way that allows me to detect when a new Connection node is added. Does anybody has done something similar?.
Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server explorer is an `IVsUIHierarchy` similiar to the solution explorer. I haven´t tried it yet, but you should get access to the server explorer hierarchy by requesting an `IVsServerExplorer` instance, like:

```
using Microsoft.VSDesigner.ServerExplorer;

...

IVsServerExplorer explorer = (IVsServerExplorer) package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsServerExplorer));
IVsUIHierarchy hierarchy;
if ((hierarchy = explorer as IVsUIHierarchy) != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Once you have the hierarchy you can subscribe for notifications...

```
IVsHierarchyEvents eventSink = new ...
uint cookie = 0;
int result = hierarchy.AdviseHierarchyEvents(eventSink, out cookie);
if (result != VSConstants.S_OK)
{
    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(result);
}
```

You need to provide an `IVsHierarchyEvents` instance; this object will receive the notifications. I suggest to implement that interface to a listener class, which handles advise and unadvise properly (you need to keep the `cookie`, in order to unsubscribe from event notification).

```
class HierarchyEventsListener : IVsHierarchyEvents, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IVsUIHierarchy hierarchy;

    private uint cookie;

    protected HierarchyEventsListener(IVsUIHierarchy hierarchy)
    {
        this.hierarchy = hierarchy;

        int hr = this.hierarchy.AdviseHierarchyEvents(this, out cookie);
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(hr);
    }

    public int OnItemAdded(uint itemidParent, uint itemidSiblingPrev, uint itemidAdded)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.cookie != 0)
        {
            this.hierarchy.UnadviseHierarchyEvents(this.cookie);
            this.cookie = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In your case you might be interested in the `OnItemAdded`- and/or `OnItemsAppended`-method, which allows you to query the newly added item...

```
public int OnItemAdded(uint itemidParent, uint itemidSiblingPrev, uint itemidAdded)
{
    const int Property = (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_Caption; // let´s ask for the caption (for instance)
    object value;
    int hr = this.hierarchy.GetProperty(itemidAdded, Property, out value);
    if (hr == VSConstants.S_OK)
    {
        ...
    }

    return VSConstants.S_OK;
}
```

Maybe you´ll need to play with it to figure out, if the added item is a connection node (guess there´s a type property or such), or not.

Comment: Hi Matze, I want to try your solution but after a while I cannot seem to find the IVsServerExplorer interfaz or proper namespace so I can include it on the references. A google search says that is under the Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.Interfaces assembly which I cannot find either. Do you know which referenced assembly I should add? Thanks

Comment: The `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.Interfaces` assembly is stored in the `GAC`, but it´s not visible in Visual Studio´s Add Reference dialog (you need to add it manually).

Comment: Tried it and it totally worked for my case. BTW the OnItemAdded notification was only fired for new connections. Thanks a lot Matze for your solution!!.

Answer (score 1):

It's too late to help gab, but I'm sure it will useful for somebody else.
Best way to "catch" connect/disconnect event - using IVsDataConnectionsService.

```
IVsDataConnectionsService service = (IVsDataConnectionsService)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsDataConnectionsService));

for (int i = 0; i < service.Count; i++)
{
    IVsDataExplorerConnection conn = service.GetConnectionHierarchy(i) as IVsDataExplorerConnection;
    //Do what you need - possible check conn.Connection.State
    //Subscribe to connection state changed
    conn.Connection.StateChanged += ConnectionStateChanged;
}
```